# Could you explain the failure of the Hodge decomposition to exist for non-compact manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, mathematical-physics, semi-riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory

I'm a physicist and the mathematics around the Hodge Decomposition is way formal than I can currently follow (I'm trying to better myself but it'll take a while).

Specifically what I'm (pragmatically) interested in is the existence of some decomposition of a (co)vector field in a $3+1$ Lorentzian manifold into (gradient of a) scalar and non-scalar parts. I understand that this is not generically possible but I was reading [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132879/hodge-decomposition-in-minkowski-space)

and a few Einstein-Maxwell papers which imply that in some (not really very physically restrictive) restricted circumstances it is possible.

So my question is what fails in attempting direct generalisation to non-compact Lorentzian manifolds? With the follow up question: is global hyperbolicity enough of a restriction to allow such a generalisation?

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to make new lines work.... I think I've found some answer: in the introduction here http://www.ams.org/journals/distribution/mmj/vol9-4-2009/troyanov.pdf


Theorem 14.3 of http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02922133


They state (and prove in the second case) that the hodge decomposition holds for any complete (Riemannian) manifold

Comment: (1) The Lorentzian and Riemannian cases are vastly different. (2) Igor's answer on the linked MO post gives a pretty good discussion. What else exactly are you looking for?